# Python giving an HTTP error 500 from Thingspeak intermiittantly

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

Here is my code

```
import os
import glob
import time
import sys
import datetime
import urllib2

baseURL = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=DCL2IZ1REQT5GUSM"
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = 'sys/bus/w1/devices/'

#Temp1 temperature device location
temp1_file = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000087787c4/w1_slave'

#Temp2 temperature Device Location
temp2_file = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000008762fa3/w1_slave'

#Determine Temp1 Temperature
def read_rawtemp_temp1():
    y = open(temp1_file,'r')
    lines = y.readlines()
    y.close
    return lines

def read_temp_temp1():
    lines = read_rawtemp_temp1()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] !='YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_rawtemp_temp1()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')

    if equals_pos !=-1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_temp1 = ((float(temp_string)/1000.0)*1.8)-32
        return temp_temp1

#Determine Temp2 Temperature

def read_rawtemp_temp2():
    x = open(temp2_file,'r')
    lines = x.readlines()
    x.close
    return lines

def read_temp_temp2():
    lines = read_rawtemp_temp2()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] !='YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_rawtemp_temp1()

    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos !=-1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_temp2 = float(temp_string)/1000.0
        return temp_temp2

while True: #Loop
#Send Temp1 Temperature to Thingspeak
    temp1_tempin = read_temp_temp1()

#Send temp2 temperature to Thingspeak
    temp2_tempin = read_temp_temp2()

#Pull results together
    values = [datetime.datetime.now(), temp1_tempin, temp2_tempin]

#Open Thingspeak channel and assign fields to temperatures
    j = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + "&field1=%s" % (temp1_tempin) + "&field2=%s" % (temp2_tempin))
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass 

#Time to next loop
time.sleep(600)
```

Here is the error that will stop the script from running after a few hours.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tempdatalog.py", line 137, in <module>
>       j = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + "&field1=%s" % (temp1_tempin) + 
> "&field2=%s" % (temp2_tempin))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

I added:

```
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass
```

this to try to get it to pass over the error, but it didn't work.  Any advice that would be given would be great, this is just the start to a monitor for a medical system in a mobile.

Comment: Please edit your question to format code properly, it will be easier to read. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to learn about posts formatting.

Comment: `x.close` does _not_ close file `x`. `x.close()` does.

Comment: You didn't enclose the `j = urllib2.urlopen(...)` inside the `try` block. The `HTTPError` was caused by that line according to your traceback info.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stacktrace, it looks like you wrapped the wrong line in the `try/except` clause.

> File "tempdatalog.py", line 137, in 
>   j = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + "&field1=%s" % (temp1_tempin) + 
>   "&field2=%s" % (temp2_tempin))

This version at least catches the exception:

```
#Open Thingspeak channel and assign fields to temperatures
try:
    j = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + "&field1=%s" % (temp1_tempin) + "&field2=%s" % (temp2_tempin))
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass
```

That still does not explain why the error appears in the first place. My guess would be a form of rate limiting

Comment: Thank you both, I'm an engineer, not a programmer.  But it's never too late to learn something new.

Comment: I tried that and it stopped updating thingspeak.  I've taken out the exception completely and changed the sleep to a longer time.  I know the error is coming from them, I'm just not sure why.